# The device version (2.1.0.1753) does not support the API level (Blackberry Native SDK 10.2)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have blackberry playbook with OS. Version 2.1.0.1753 i have connected with WIFI. Now when i run project it will start executing project into my playbook

but every time i got below error

[image]

Then i click on **update the project's API level**

[image]

Then i click ok button i got below dialog box

[image]
I do not know what should i have to do, Do i need to install all API for example
**10.1, 10.0**

Comment: There is no BB10 OS level for the Playbook.  Are you intending to develop exclusively for the PlayBook, or was this just the only test device you had available?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. and dont know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have already found the solution for your problem but personally I'm using a different Blackberry NDK for Playbook development: [Link to Playbook NDK](http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/native/download/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as i've been told the playbook os is pretty different from the blackberry z10/q10.
Playbook is 2.x and z10 is 10.0/.1/.2

Momentics is only suitable for 10.1

For publishing to playbook youll need the playbok "tablet" sdk
https://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/native/download/

Also i've been told NOT to install both sdks on the same machine. as """because weirdness happens when you have both tablet and bb10 sdks installed. it's nominally "not a bug", but merely "unsupported". """